# Font with two variants: one where every character is an underscore and a usual one

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, font-design

I currently have a few workbooks published for my students that have fill in the blanks portions.

For example,

> The sampling method is first ____________ sampling to choose a random street and then _____________ because you sample every other house. We can define a random variable X to be ___________________.

The blanks are the type in white font style. In Word I can update the font style to red with three clicks (I use *Update STYLE* to match selection). I then provide a PDF version with the answers in filled in.

> The sampling method is first **cluster** sampling to choose a random street and then **systematic** because you sample every other house. We can define a random variable X to be “**The number of houses that are white.” Then X=21.**

This works but I would prefer underscores instead of blank space.

#### Question

Is there a font with two variants; the usual version and a version where every character and space is replaced by an underscore (_), but still has the same spacing and line breaks? Changing between the variants should not change the word placement on the page. **Or:** Is there a way for me to easily create such a variant?

I know of many other teachers who make similar workbooks by manually entering thousands of instances of underscores, which takes to long. This could really help us.

Comment: I don't have access to Word right now, but in InDesign it's possible to make a text white, but have another color for the underlines. Isn't that possible in Word?

Comment: beware though if you release PDF files then fonts can be copied. Visible or not any person who copes a placeholder will see this. Even just underscores this is how UK leaked submarine capabilities. Much better to just use underscores. You can use search and replace to put them in Now be aware that again you may lek the length of your answer.

Comment: Also as a teacher you should know that this is sort of a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) except you have done quite well in explaining the background. Your suggested solution is not really super conductive in solving your problem for may reasons. To be honest i am a bit saddened by the lack of even rudimentary computer skills with many teachers. IN either case none of the solutions i perfect if you intend for page to be entirely intact as that would mean youd need to take in account keerning. And that would be prohibitively much work. May be best to script this.

Comment: … I just want to add that this is very easy to solve with LaTeX.

Comment: @jooja: For InDesign that is exactly what I would propose – a style that shows underline and hides text. Funny enough, if you set the text color to [None] in InDesign, it is not exported to a PDF at all! Which makes sense. "White", as the OP would need to use in Word, is a valid text color. Just changing the background color would defeat it. However, the PDF color model has no "No Color" for text, so InDesign just moves the cursor.

Comment: How about this? (Warning: highly technical ) 1. Make a copy of your font. 2. Add a new character `underscore.a`, `underscore.b` etc. for all characters that you use, with the correct width for each character. *The Unicode value must be that of the regular underscore*. 3. Add an OpenType rule for each character to replace `sub a' by underscore.a;` 4. Put these rules in the Required feature. Now all text in this font will appear as underscores in the PDF, even after copying. ...I think I should try this some time.

Comment: No human is going to write, by hand, in the same space a typeset word uses. Typeset words are much, much, much smaller than handwriting. Just use underscores... you don't need a font.

Comment: @usr2564301 except it can now not substitute normal letter by changing font

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Create your own custom font

You can easily create your own custom font(s) for this. A quick web search finds [FontStruct](https://fontstruct.com) and [Calligrapher](https://www.calligraphr.com/en/pricing) are free options, though I have never tried either one myself and I can no longer find what software I used when I did this for fun back in high school.

This is closest to the answer you requested, but if you are distributing workbooks electronically then it's trivial for students to cheat and get the hidden answers back. All they have to do is copy the hidden answer text from the PDF, paste it into another program, and change the color/font/underline/etc to get the answers readable again.

If your workbooks are only distributed in printed form, then copy-paste doesn't exist so this isn't a problem.

## Search and replace (only safe option for electronically-distributed PDF workbooks)

Another option is actually replacing all characters in that style with underscores, with a Find and Replace All. Even if students get the PDFs with the blank spaces, copying the text into another program and changing font/color/underline/whatever only reveals the number of letters in the answer, but not the answer itself. Note to keep the same spacing and line breaks, your answers must use a monospace font like `Consolas`, `Courier New`, or one of the more normal-looking [monospace fonts on Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace). If you use a regular font, the spacings will all slightly expand as underscores `_` characters are wider than characters like `i`. To do the replacement,

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Find and Replace dialogue
2. Click *More >>*.
3. Enable the *Use wildcards* option
4. Put `?` in the *Find what* box (this is a wildcard matching any single character)
5. Put `_` in the *Replace with* box.
6. At the bottom-left of the window, click *Format* → *Style* → *YOURSTYLE Char* (you need to select your style ending in `Char`, since you applied the style to individual word characters and not entire paragraphs, see [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190903224211/http://homepage.swissonline.ch/cindymeister/MyFavTip.htm) for more info).
7. Select *Replace All* and save a copy of the document (since this is permanently removing information).

[image: Microsoft Word Search and Replace with Style and Wildcard]

## Style with white text and black (not automatic) underline

This option takes the least amount of work, but is also easily cheated from an electronic PDF. Idea comes from @Wolff in his comment above.

It is also possible to create a Word style with white text and a black underline. You said you know how to use *Update  Style to match selection*, so just do this with some text with white text and a black underline. Note, you must set the underline color to *Black* and not leave it on *Automatic*.

[image: Set black underline color]

[image: Update style to match selection]

Comment: The last method is the only one that dont possibly leak info

Comment: @joojaa I almost 100% agree, although the OP only said the answer key is shared as an electronic PDF. The blank student workbooks could be distributed on paper and not electronically, and that would also be pretty much bullet proof. Students could guess words based on the length of the underline, but that's likely more work than completing the worksheet as intended.

Comment: Yes but considering that we are in lock down around most of the world. Its safe to assume that the teacher may in fact also need to think about digital distribution. In which case HTML would be a much better idea though

Comment: Altough i dont know if any of these solutions actually solve the may not change the documents layout.

Comment: @joojaa Edited answer to emphasize the safe method, and to use monospaced font for the answers to avoid a change in spacing (only avoids spacing change when going from hidden to shown answers, obviously spacing changes when the font is changed. But I think OP is fine with this as was looking for a different font in the first place).

Comment: Thank you Micah Lindstrom, your last suggestion about underline black is perfect! So simple. I have never used workbooks for homework (just handouts for lecture so students don't rewrite problems or zone out). If I ever create homework with this, I will consider the replace underscore method.

Answer (score 3):

I've created worksheets of this kind and you have to bear in mind, before anything else, that a handwritten answer is going to take up TWICE as much width as the answer printed, and TWICE as much height vertically, at any normal size of font. Fonts are *far* more compact than a hand-written answer, so replacing a printed answer with an equivalent width space never works out, let alone if the student needs to make changes. Also, you have to have white space above and below the answer: you cannot, cannot, CANNOT mark out a space in the middle of a block of text (like this: _________________) and expect students to fill an answer into that space.

Sure, people can write smaller, but it's really uncomfortable, especially for young people, try it and you'll see.

So my first recommendation is to put all answers at the end of a line, and convert them to white, like below. Leave a line above and below each question. Export a copy: that's your question sheet. Select all text, convert to black, that's your answer sheet. Also lets people quickly run their eye down the list of questions and compare the questions with the answers side-by-side. Ideal format looks like this:

Write an answer here:

And also here:

The other good option is a two-column table with the questions in one and answers in the other. Same idea.